# Thick noodle soup minus cornstarch/cornflour?

Tags: soup, noodles

How do we thicken noodles soup without using cornstarch? List of ingredients at hand:

1. Onions
2. Tomatoes
3. Worsterchire Sauce
4. Soy Sauce
5. Salt
6. Ginger& Garlic(fresh)
7. Star Anise
8. Cilantro
9. Noodles

Comment: Using only those ingredients, i.e. no starch of any kind, not just no corn starch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cook the noodles using as little water as possible and use that water for your soup, or cook them directly in the soup, so that you get all the starch from them.

If that's not thick enough, the only other thing on your list that can really help is the onion and tomato: if you grind them smooth they'll at least add some substance to the soup. You could take it a step further by cooking them down to get rid of excess water and get a thicker paste.

Comment: Using starch from noodles & incorporating onion-tomato paste will do the trick, i guess. A little caveat, onion-tomato paste will have to be completely cooked before using. Thanks @Jefromi .

Comment: @SaurabhCooks Cooking them to enough of a paste to really thicken the soup (as opposed to just adding body to the liquid) is way beyond just completely cooked.

Comment: Even the fresh ginger and garlic (and maybeso cilantro) might help thicken the soup, if ground to a paste and/or blended into the liquid - although not very much thickness would be added, given the quantities that would be used to flavor the soup, it might help just a tad.

Comment: Hi @Megha, it's true. The paste can help in thickening the soup but i am going to use it while cooking tomatoes which is beforehand also i would like to use both of these spices in moderation because i wud like to add a hint of garlicy flavor and gingery tang to my soup. It might not work in my context but can totally help.

Comment: Tomato and onion paste is a common curry base that needs no further thickening if you don't want it fork-stiff...

Comment: @rackandboneman If you actually make it out of tomato and onion paste, yup! I suggested additional thickening because it sounded like the OP might want to thicken an existing soup and get a result more like a starch-thickened soup, rather than just make tomato soup and put noodles in it, so using thickened tomato paste to supplement very starchy water might be closer to the desired texture.

Comment: But then, the thickening effect you want for a soup is a very subtle one, compared to a thick curry :)